# Xcode 8 Swift 3 Core Data too many ent

Tags: core-data

I'm just starting to learn to work with Core Data in Swift 3.  I am trying to save and retrieve some variables for a basic game to learn, however every time it saves/retrieves it creates an additional value.  Now i'm up to 75 entries, each with a set of the variables.  I'd like to have 1 that i can work with.  Is there a way to keep the total to 1 (delete the old before new one saved).

Or is there a better way to data handle between viewControllers?

Thanks.

```
func retrieveCoreData() {
    //        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Variables")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do
    {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        if results.count > 0 {
            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]
            {
                atHome = result.value(forKey: "atHome") as! Int
                playerGold = result.value(forKey: "playerGold") as! Int
                battleBoss = result.value(forKey: "battleBoss") as! Bool
                enemyAttack = result.value(forKey: "enemyAttack") as! Int
                enemyDefense = result.value(forKey: "enemyDefense") as! Int
                enemyHealth = result.value(forKey: "enemyHealth") as! Int
                enemyHealthMax = result.value(forKey: "enemyHealthMax") as! Int
                inBattle = result.value(forKey: "inBattle") as! Bool
                playerAttack = result.value(forKey: "playerAttack") as! Int
                playerDefense = result.value(forKey: "playerDefense") as! Int
                playerGold = result.value(forKey: "playerGold") as! Int
                playerHealth = result.value(forKey: "playerHealth") as! Int
                playerLevel = result.value(forKey: "playerLevel") as! Int
                playerLevelUpgradeValue = result.value(forKey: "playerLevelUpgradeValue") as! Int

            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        fatalError("Failed to recover CoreData: \(error)")
    }

}
```

Here is a list of the values printed:  (note "p12")

```
<Variables: 0x1466d150> (entity: Variables; id: 0x14644960 <x-coredata://2E613846-F77C-4492-B27E-5A79AEC58949/Variables/p12> ; data: {
    atHome = 1;
    battleBoss = 0;
    enemyAttack = 1;
    enemyDefense = 1;
    enemyHealth = 1;
    enemyHealthMax = 1;
    inBattle = 0;
    playerAttack = 6;
    playerDefense = 3;
    playerGold = 0;
    playerHealth = 200;
    playerHealthMax = 0;
    playerLevel = 1;
    playerLevelUpgradeValue = 350;
})
```

Comment: Where is your code where you create a `Variables` entity?  Are you testing to see if there already is one before creating another one?

Comment: The "Variables" is the name of the CoreData called upon in the first block of text and the actual variables are initialized upon load, to which the core data is stored and restored into.   In the debug menu i can get it to print out the above list times the number of entries.  My main testing device has 75+ instances

Comment: Yes but what Jon is getting at is, somewhere your code must be creating all these instances, and that's the code you need to include in your question. You're creating instances you don't want, so show the code where you're creating them.